# JQuery validator - Bootstrap - DO NOT validate a specific input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, bootstrap-5

There's a way with JQuery validator to validate all the form, but do not validate a specific input?

Here a Code Snippet example for this:

```js
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: true,
        success: "valid"
    });
    
    jQuery('.needs-validation').validate({
        errorElement: "em",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            // Add the `invalid-feedback` class to the error element
            error.addClass("invalid-feedback");

            if (element.prop("type") === "checkbox") {
                error.insertAfter(element.next("label"));
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).addClass("is-invalid").removeClass("is-valid");
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).addClass("is-valid").removeClass("is-invalid");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate="novalidate">       
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="a" class="form-label">Text 1</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="a" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="b" class="form-label">Text 2</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="b" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

It's possible to validate the `input#a`, but not validate the `textarea#b`?

Answer (score 0):

For each one that has my same problem just add `ignore` in `validate({})` with a selector like `.ignore`.

P.S. Default it's `:hidden`

```js
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});

jQuery('.needs-validation').validate({
  ignore: ".ignore",
  errorElement: "em",
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    // Add the `invalid-feedback` class to the error element
    error.addClass("invalid-feedback");

    if (element.prop("type") === "checkbox") {
      error.insertAfter(element.next("label"));
    } else {
      error.insertAfter(element);
    }
  },
  highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass("is-invalid").removeClass("is-valid");
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass("is-valid").removeClass("is-invalid");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate="novalidate">       
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="a" class="form-label">Text 1</label>
      <input type="email" name="a" class="form-control" id="a" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="b" class="form-label">Text 2</label>
      <textarea class="form-control ignore" name="b" id="b" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  <div class="form-check form-switch mb-3">
  <input class="form-check-input ignore" type="checkbox" name="something">
  </div>
  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
</form>
```